# Firestore addDocument completion handler not called when iPhone in airplane mode

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

It's late at night here and I haven't used Firebase in a long time, so I may be missing something here.

But this completion handler is never called when the device is in `airplane mode` or the network is unaccessible.

How am I meant to handle this? I would have assumed `err` would state an error, however `isLoading = false` is never reached inside the closure when there's no connectivity.

```swift
    func addUser() {
        var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
        ref = db.collection("users").addDocument(data: [
            "first": "Ada",
            "last": "Lovelace",
            "born": 1815
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error adding document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
            }
            
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Firestore doesn't return an error on network unavailability because it doesn't consider it an error because it's offline-capable. Write operations are queued until connectivity returns and then retried automatically.

Comment: @bsod That's a great answer which should be posted as an answer! OP: Did you check to see if that data was written? If it was not, you've got something else causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore doesn't return an error on network unavailability because it doesn't consider it an error because it's offline-capable. Write operations are queued until connectivity returns and then retried automatically.